# Laravel 10 Repository Pattern with multiple database connections

Tags: laravel, eloquent, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, laravel-10

#### TL;DR;

How can I get multiple repositories with different DB connections when using Repository Pattern.

#### About

Hello, I'm building an API Server using Laravel 10.
I choose Repository Pattern for testing, but struggled with multiple DB connections issue.

#### What I want

- Declare multiple repositories in the controller.
  Ex) $user_repo01, $user_repo02, ...
- On controller's constructor, each repository is assigned with injected interface.
- Each repository should have different DB connection.
  Ex) $user_repo01 is connected to 'db01' while $user_repo02 is connected to 'db02'

#### What I did

Added `setConnection($connection)` into my `BaseRepository`.
This calls Eloquent Model's `setConnection($connection)` to change the connection.
Also added `getConnectionNames()` to retrive connection's name.
On controller's constuctor, get injected interface and assign to repository.
Before assigning, changed connection.

#### Problem

Calling '/user/test' should returns connection names by repository.

- What I expected is

  ```json
  {
      'user_repo01': 'db01',
      'user_repo02': 'db02',
      'user_repo03': 'db03',
  }
  ```
- But the result is...

  ```json
  {
      'user_repo01': 'db03',
      'user_repo02': 'db03',
      'user_repo03': 'db03',
  }
  ```

It seems injected interface is shared with all the repositories.
Not sure why, I just started applying Repository Pattern and I don't know much about it.
What I missed? How can I achieve what I want?

#### Codes

###### config/database.php

```php
'connections' => [
    'db01' => [ ... ],
    'db02' => [ ... ],
    'db03' => [ ... ],
]
```

###### app/Repositories/Interfaces/BaseRepositoryInterface.php

```php
interface BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function setConnection(string $connection);
    public function getConnectionName();
}
```

###### app/Repositories/BaseRepository.php

```php
class BaseRepository implements BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function setConnection(string $connection) {
        $this->model->setConnection($connection);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getConnectionName() {
        return $this->model->getConnectionName();
    }
}
```

###### app/Repositories/Interfaces/UserRepositoryInterface.php

```php
interface UserRepositoryInterface extends BaseRepositoryInterface
{

}
```

###### app/Repositories/UserRepository.php

```php
class UserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(User $model) {
        parent::__construct($model);
    }
}
```

###### app/Providers/RepositoryServiceProvider.php

```php
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, UserRepository::class);
    }
}
```

###### app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $user_repo01;
    private $user_repo02;
    private $user_repo03;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $user_repo) {
        $this->user_repo01 = $user_repo->setConnection('db01');
        $this->user_repo02 = $user_repo->setConnection('db02');
        $this->user_repo03 = $user_repo->setConnection('db03');
    }

    /**
     * /user/test
     */
    public function test() {
        return [
            'user_repo01' => $this->user_repo01->getConnectionName(),
            'user_repo02' => $this->user_repo02->getConnectionName(),
            'user_repo03' => $this->user_repo03->getConnectionName(),
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answered.
Changed to returning instance via `resolve()`, also separated `getInstance()` from `setConnection()`

#### app/Repositories/Interfaces/BaseRepositoryInterface.php

```php
Interface BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getInstance(?string $connection = null): self;
    public function setConnection(string $connection);
    public function getConnectionName(): ?string;
}
```

#### app/Repositories/BaseRepository.php

```php
class BaseRepository implements BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getInstance(?string $connection = null): self {
        $new_instance = resolve($this::class);

        if($connection)
            $new_instance->setConnection($connection);

        return $new_instance;
    }

    public function setConnection(string $connection) {
        $this->model->setConnection($connection);
    }

    public function getConnectionName(): ?string {
        return $this->model->getConnectionName();
    }
}
```

#### app/Http/Constrollers/UserController.php

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $user_repo01;
    private $user_repo02;
    private $user_repo03;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $user_repo) {
        $this->user_repo01 = $user_repo->getInstance('db01');
        $this->user_repo02 = $user_repo->getInstance('db02');
        $this->user_repo03 = $user_repo->getInstance('db03');
    }

    /**
     * /user/test
     */
    public function test() {
        return [
            'user_repo01' => $this->user_repo01->getConnectionName(),
            'user_repo02' => $this->user_repo02->getConnectionName(),
            'user_repo03' => $this->user_repo03->getConnectionName(),
        ];
    }
```

#### Result

```json
{
    'user_repo01': 'db01',
    'user_repo02': 'db02',
    'user_repo03': 'db03',
}
```